# Best way to submit multiple input fields jQuery/PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to upgrade my like-system to something more practical.

Currently I have it like `<a href="https://mysite/dash.php?like=<? echo $postid; ?>">Like</a>` then in the PHP have something like: if $_GET['like'] is set, then grab the user's ID and the post ID and call a function called `like_status($post_id,$user_id);`

However, I've been working on something like this:

**The main part that shows on the statuses:**

```
<script src="https://mysite/stuff/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://mysite/stuff/js/global.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="postid" value="<? echo $postid; ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="userid" value="<? echo $session_user_id; ?>">
<span id="like-button" style="color:red;">Like</span>
```

**The Javascript/jQuery:**

```
$('span#like-button').on('click', function(){
    var postid = $('input#postid').val();
    var userid = $('input#userid').val();
    if (postid != ''){
        $.post('https://mysite/stuff/ajax/like.php', {postid: postid, userid: userid}, function(data){
            document.getElementById('like-button').innerHTML = data;
        });
    }
});
```

and finally,
**My like.php script:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['postid']) === true && empty($_POST['userid']) === false){
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/stuff/init.php';
    if(is_liked($_POST['postid'],$_POST['userid']) === true){
        unlike_status($_POST['postid'],$_POST['userid']);
        echo 'Like';
    } else {
        like_status($_POST['postid'],$_POST['userid']);
        echo 'Unlike';
    }
}
?>
```

My unlike/like functions work fine. I have a working like system now, but it makes the user refresh and everything every time, and it's very inconvenient. I'd like to use this method to automatically update the like button without having to refresh the page or anything. This way, users can like multiple things on the page, and not have to refresh the page every time. I also think it's more secure since the $_GET['like'] can be changed to any id, even if user's aren't friends with other users, or the status doesn't exist.

## My issue:

Okay, so whenever I click the like button, nothing happens. I tried this in a separate page as well (changing the type from hidden to text, and manually inputting the data) and it didn't work either. It seems the javascript doesn't execute. I've opened up console in google chrome, and when I click the button, nothing happens. The like doesn't get posted to the database, and the button doesn't get updated.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong? Possibly point me in the right direction to fixing this?

---

## UPDATE

I tried combining the Javascript/HTML in one page to have dynamic variables.

This is what shows up for each status:

```
<script src="https://mysite/stuff/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="Javascript">
$(document.body).on('click','#like-button', function(
        var postid<? echo $status_id; ?> = $('input#postid<? echo $status_id; ?>').val();
        var userid<? echo $status_id; ?> = $('input#userid<? echo $status_id; ?>').val();
        $.post('https://mysite/stuff/ajax/like.php', {postid: postid<? echo $status_id; ?>, userid: userid<? echo $status_id; ?>}, function(data){
            document.getElementById('like-button').innerHTML = data;
        });
));
</script>
<input type="hidden" id="postid<? echo $status_id; ?>" value="<? echo $status_id; ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="userid<? echo $status_id; ?>" value="<? echo $session_user_id; ?>">
<span id="like-button" style="color:red;"><? if(isliked($status_id,$session_user_id) === true){ ?>Unlike<? } else { ?>Like<?}?></span>
```

I still can't get it to execute the script.

Comment: Did you debug the click event on chrome developer tools? To look if it enters the event? Or you can observe the AJAX transmission via the network tab there. if it has some error on the PHP side, it'll show you the error there.

Comment: OP said he checked console, but more than likely network tab is going to be more useful in this situation.

Comment: Yeah, nothing shows up in network tab, and do you mean check in console and such to see if there's any events when I click? Because I did and nothing came up. I went to sources tab, and clicked on "event listener breakpoint" and added mouse->onclick but nothing in the log pertains to the script I made. I'm not sure if it's just not able to read the ID properly or there's a typo somewhere, etc. It just seems that the javascript file isn't executing on click.

Comment: If nothing in network tab means the request was never sent, definitely points to JQuery issue. Try putting an `alert` or `console.log` inside your click event to see if it's firing. You'll also need a `return false;` directly afterward to prevent a page refresh. If no output from that it's probably a problem with your selector.

Comment: Instead of changing everything you need to debug.

Comment: I've tried `alert('Yes');` and `console.log('Works');` but nothing. It's something to do with getting the element's ID? Or, maybe the clicking event listener?

Comment: More than likely yes, seems that JQuery can't find `#like-button` in the DOM.

Comment: Another possibility is that `<script src="https://mysite/stuff/jquery.min.js"></script>` is not available. Double check that. But if that was a the case you would probably see an error in the console.

Comment: I tried substituting it with `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` and still no luck :/

Comment: Question; does it being nested in multiple <div>'s have anything to do with it? I include my site's layout, so it's inside a few divs.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always just use `$('#fomrm_id').serialize()`, to get all the form fields at once in `POST data`. It refreshes page because you have to add `return false;` to the end of `jQuery.click` event.

If those elements are being created dynamically (or as in your case script is being executed before they are created), you need to set proper `.on` event, this one is not good, as it binds to the element that may not be there.

Should be rather:

`$(document.body).on('click','#like-button', function(){..});` - that will bind it to `document body`, that is always there, but will check for selector in second argument if it matches.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what I wanted to do, but it's good enough. I managed to get the like button to work/update without refreshing and such. Thanks to everyone for the help if it wasn't for your suggestions I would've never found this out.

```
<input type="hidden" id="postid" value="<? echo $status_id; ?>"><br>
<input type="hidden" id="userid" value="<? echo $session_user_id; ?>"><br>
<span id="like-button" style="color:red;"><? if(isliked($status_id,$session_user_id) === true){ ?>Unlike<? } else { ?>Like<? } ?></span>
<script>
$('span#like-button').on('click', function(){
    var postid = $('input#postid').val();
    var userid = $('input#userid').val();
    <? if(isliked($status_id,$session_user_id) === true){ ?>
    $.get('https://mysite/dash', {unlike: postid, userid: userid}, function(data){
        document.getElementById('like-button').innerHTML = 'Like';
    });
    <? } else { ?>
    $.get('https://mysite/dash', {like: postid, userid: userid}, function(data){
        document.getElementById('like-button').innerHTML = 'Unike';
    });
    <? } ?>
});
</script>
```